# Query to show the services that have been requested less than 3 times

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to create a query that brings back the results of any services that have only been requested less than 3 times.

The tables i believe to be involved in this query will be my Booking Table, my Services table, and my members table.

A lot of these columns wont be relevant so i will not include them to save space.

My tables include the below columns

Booking Table
-Booking_ID
-Service_Name_FK
-Member_Name_FK

Services Table
-Service_ID
-Service_Name
-Charge_per_Service

Members Table
-Member_ID
-Member_Name (The pet)
-Owner_Name (The actual owner of this pet)

I gave the below a try along with different things but couldn't get it to work.

```
SELECT `Booking_ID`, `Member_Name_FK`, COUNT(DISTINCT`Service_ID_FK`) AS Services_Count
FROM Booking
GROUP BY Booking_ID, Member_Name_FK, Service_ID_FK
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Service_ID_FK) < 3
```

Just need the services requested less than 3 times in a list :)

Any edits/questions for more info are welcome. I hope this will be enough information for you to understand my question.

Comment: You will have an easier time getting help by including some sample data for each table along with the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What's the best way of doing this. I can screenshot my tables if that helps?

Comment: Please _don't_ take screenshots as this won't help.  Include the data as text tables.  Expect to spend at least 5-10 minutes asking a question here.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info provided, you can do this from one table:

```
select service_name_fk, count(booking_id) as requested
from Booking
group by service_name_fk
having count(booking_id) <3
```

Then just join to this query to populate the other info

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is trying to count services per booking, but you want bookings per service. The easiest approach is probably counting in a subquery:

```
select *
from services s
where 3 >
(
  select count(*)
  from booking b
  where b.service_name_fk = s.service_name
);
```

(It is a bad idea to link the tables via service name by the way. The whole idea of having a service ID is that you can use this for references and be able to change the service name at any time you want without having to worry about other tables referring to that service.)

Comment: Totally makes sense. Appreciate the comment. The issue i had was i'm not exactly   good with sql/databased as im sure you can see from my terrible knowledge haha. I needed the tables to show the table name in text rather than displaying a number for the ID. To do this i ended up creating an internal relationship which for what i needed worked. Can definitely see where this could go wrong in the long run though. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.